# Putting Firebase Data Into Array to Be Put Into Text View (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, firebase

So I've been trying to put some Firebase data into an array in Swift, so I can then put it into a text field. Everything is working, however, my text view is empty and contains no rows and no data. Does anyone know why this is happening? My code is below (I've imported Firebase and UIKit at the top, don't know why Stack Overflow doesn't let me put that in..sorry about that):

```
class SummaryEmployeesFeelingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    struct Feedback {
        let id: Int
        let feeling: String
        let date: Timestamp
    }


    var feedbackarray = [Feedback]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let summarydb = Firestore.firestore()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addDatatoArray()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feedbackarray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let feedbackcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier")!

        let text = feedbackarray[indexPath.row] as? String

        feedbackcell.textLabel?.text = text

        return feedbackcell
    }

    func addDatatoArray(){
        summarydb.collection("employeefeedback").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error == nil && snapshot != nil{
                for document in snapshot!.documents{
                    var idValue = document.get("id")
                    var feelingValue = document.get("feeling")
                    var dateValue = document.get("date")
                    let newEntry = Feedback(id: idValue as! Int, feeling: feelingValue as! String, date: dateValue as! Timestamp)
                    self.feedbackarray.append(newEntry)

                }
        }
    }


}


}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload your tableView after getting the data

```
 func addDatatoArray(){
    summarydb.collection("employeefeedback").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error == nil && snapshot != nil{
            for document in snapshot!.documents{
                var idValue = document.get("id")
                var feelingValue = document.get("feeling")
                var dateValue = document.get("date")
                let newEntry = Feedback(id: idValue as! Int, feeling: feelingValue as! String, date: dateValue as! Timestamp)
                self.feedbackarray.append(newEntry)

            }
          print("count:\(self.feedbackarray.count)")
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.reloadData()
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Also set tableView delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addDatatoArray()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    }
```

Also update your this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let feedbackcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier")!

        let feedBack = feedbackarray[indexPath.row] as? Feedback

        feedbackcell.textLabel?.text = feedBack.feeling

        return feedbackcell
    }
```

Comment: Hi @jawadAli, I did that, but no data appears in the table view. My database does have data however. There is a cell, but there is nothing inside of it.

Comment: please check print("count:\(self.feedbackarray.count)") and let me know

Comment: i updated my answer ... where to get count of feedbackarray ... i want to see if it has data or not ?

Comment: Hi @jawadAli, when I print (feedbackarray.count), the output is 1. But, I added the id, date, and feeling to the array. So should it print out 1 or 3?

Comment: you are adding newEntry in array ... newEntry have  id, date, and feeling 
so it will print 1 ... so you should have one row of table ...

Comment: Okay, thanks! So why is it not showing up in my table view?

Comment: updated my answer ... update your `cellForRowAt` method ... each index of your array have `Feedback` struct ... not string ... cast it with `Feedback` struct

Comment: thanks! But why do I need to say `.feeling` after feedbackcell.textLabel?.text = feedBack? Because I want one cell to say the id, the next to say the feeling, and the next to say the date... so would I have to assign each and every cell the value?

Comment: As i told you ... you have struct on each index of your feedbackarray ... so you cast it with  Feedback ... now you have Feedback object ... which have  id , feeling and date ...what do you want to show in cell ?

Comment: would it be possible to have multiple cells and have different value types for each of them? Such as one cell having an id, the next having a feeling, and the next having the date value?

Comment: yes we can convert id and timeStamp to string ... and can have three cells for each value

Comment: thank you! So for that, how would I do it without manually creating cells in storyboard and assigning values? Thanks!

Comment: you will not use Feedback struct then ?

Comment: would it be possible to use feedback struct still?

Comment: for which purpose you want to use that ?

Comment: you can show three values like , id , feeling and date in one cell by the way

Comment: oh! How would I do that? That's exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: do you have custom cell class ?

Comment: create a custom cell class .... having 3 iboutlets of uilabel ... and in cellForRow method ... return that cell after setting all three values

Comment: Where I would i put it in my view controller?

Comment: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/ ... here is a tutorial ... how you can achieve that =) happy coding .. please accept my answer ...